# "me doing something" or "my doing something"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please which one of the following sentences is correct.

> I cannot explain **me** having hired him.
>
> I cannot explain **my** having hired him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot explain **my having** hired him.  (correct)

**Explanation**

In this sentence, "having" is a gerund (a gerund can take the place of a noun) and so "my having" is correct.

Here is another example:

> **The Special Verbs That Are Also Nouns - Gerunds in English**
>
> "I never believe nor disbelieve. If you will excuse **my speaking**
>   frankly, I mean to observe you closely, and to decide for myself."
>   (Wilkie Collins, Percy and the Prophet, 1877)
>
> https://www.thoughtco.com/gerund-in-grammar-1690897